# Spotify SDK Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

I am developing an application, but I have never used the Spotify SDK. I managed to get the user login & authorization going despite the tutorial being in Obj-C but my question is in regards to streaming music and pulling down users information. Basically I am trying display the users name and give them access to their songs via my app which then they can use with features I will implement. Is anyone familiar with working with the Spotify SDK and/or could give me a hint as to how I can manage to do the above. Thanks.

Best regards,

Andres

Answer (score 0):

This info is [in the documentation](https://github.com/spotify/ios-sdk).

To access the user's info:

1. You need to have the `SPTAuthUserReadPrivateScope` scope
2. call `STPUser.requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:callback:`. [Documentation](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTUser.html#//api/name/requestCurrentUserWithAccessToken:callback:)

To access the user's playlists:

1. These 2 scopes: `SPTAuthPlaylistReadScope` and `SPTAuthPlaylistReadPrivateScope`
2. Call `STPPlaylistList.playlistsForUser:withAccessToken:callback:`. [Documentation](https://spotify.github.io/ios-sdk/Classes/SPTPlaylistList.html)

Comment: I have the scopes requested in a setup function that is called on ViewDidLoad and I call the STPUser.requested..... but I get nil for display name